# how to regenerate an UI stochastically in QML using a Button on the interface?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml

I am working on the following **QML framework** for *music apps user-interface prototyping:*

https://github.com/tiagmoraismorgado/TMM_QML_UI_UX_FRAMEWORK_WIP  in the file **instiationTest**, i need to add a type **Button1_1** and then use it to **regenerate the whole gui** based on **combostochasticselector**.

i know i have to **instantiate** the **randomPicking()** function, from the **instantiationtest** file, on top of the **mouseArea** **Pressed** statement of **Button1_1**, but i am not being able to do so.

if anyone could provide me any insight i would be pretty thankful

here is the code of the main file

```
(...)
Window {

id: root
width: Screen.width
height: Screen.height
visible: true
visibility: "FullScreen"
title: qsTr("instantiationTest")
color: "black"

CombosStochasticSelector {}
}
```

on the combostochasticselector, you can see the following:

```
Item {
property var model: model1
anchors.fill: parent

id: randomMIDIkeyboardSelector;

property var random: 0;

function randomSelection(min, max) {(...)}

function createMidiKeyboard(itemToBeInstantiated) {
    var component = Qt.createComponent(itemToBeInstantiated)
    if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
        var midiKeyboard = component.createObject(randomMIDIkeyboardSelector, {model: model});
    }
    else if (component.status === Component.Error) {
    }
}

function randomPicking() {
    random = parseInt(randomSelection(1, 13));
    if(random == 1) {createMidiKeyboard("./../_Combos/Combo1.qml");}
    (...)
    return random;
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    randomPicking();
}

}
```

on the Button1_1 you can see the following:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
QMLOpenGLToggleButtonPrimitive {}
```

It instantiates a press released kind of button made out of **Rectangle QML Primitives**

kind regards
**Tiago**

Comment: please minimize your code. no one will browse the whole repository

Comment: I have no clue, what you try to achieve. Your question is hard to read, my eyes are bleeding. You might consider marking 90% of your **bold** parts as `code`. For rest, *italic* might improve the readability, for it being less agressive. Futher it is quite common to start sentences with capital letters. I don't want to blame your grammar or spelling, as I fail at those as well. But once you made your text readable at all, you might also think about, how you might clarify what it is, you try to achive. Maybe without words like *combostochasticselector* which I can't find in any dictionary.